# How to center grouped UI elements in a UIView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

iOS newbie here.

I have three UI elements (one `UIImageView` and two `UILabel`s) that are added to a `UIView` (*that fills the whole screen*)

How do I center them to the middle of the screen, both vertically and horizontally?

Comment: You can do what you want to do with AutoLayout or with struts and springs, but the method is different depending on which you are using. Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

By using the Auto-Layout concept. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

In code, without autolayout, you could use autoresizingmasks #oldschool:

```
imageview.center = view.center;
label.center = view.center;
imageview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the verbose AutoLayout syntax, you can set a view's center X and Y coordinates.

```
[containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:otherView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                                             toItem:containerView  
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:0]];

[containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:otherView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                                             toItem:containerView  
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:0]];
```

You can also use an XIB to do this.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working...could it be it's because I'm using [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)?